# Change database schema using dynamodb module in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the dynamodb package in a NodeJS project 
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb) and I would like to change the existing database schema because I need to add a document with different fields into the existing table. Due to the initial database schema declaration that dynamodb requires, I am not able to do that. Is there a solution where I don't need to migrate the table to a new table?

Comment: Do you need to change the primary key or range key? If not, there's no need to change anything, just go ahead and insert the new document. Apart from the two keys, Dynamo is schema-less.

Comment: The package dynamodb requires a schema definition when defining the model of the table, so later when you want to add a new document who differs from the initial schema you are not able to do it. This property basically makes the DynamoDB relational.

Comment: To which package exactly are you referring to, can you post a link? Is it an ORM or something similar for Dynamo? The official DynamoDB API doesn't require you to declare a schema.